# How to read quoted CSV in Spark 3.4.0 with escape characters?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a CSV with the following data:

```
"1", "2", "Learn more https:\/\/example.com"
```

What would be the options to escape the URL correctly?

```
sparkSession.read().options(?).csv("trouble.csv")
```

So that, when I read the CSV the expected dataframe looks like the following data:

```
1,2,Learn more https://example.com
```

And, I can write another CSV out without the quotes and escaping the char `\` correctly:

```
1, 2, Learn more https:\/\/example.com
```

I can only get it to write as if the escaping char is part of the URL.

```
1, 2, Learn more https:\\/\\/example.com
```

Comment: There is no need to escape `/` in CSV (unless that is the separator character), so it is odd that it is in your source, and not surprising you can't get them escaped when writing out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options related to quoting described in [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html) about CSV reading/writing, relevant here is:

> **quote** (") - Sets a single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. For reading, if you would like to turn off quotations, you need to set not null but an empty string. For writing, if an empty string is set, it uses u0000 (null character).
>
> **escape** (\) - Sets a single character used for escaping quotes inside an already quoted value.

Note that *escape* says it's for escaping quotes, while in your file it's the slash that's escaped. Therefore it won't work with built-in options. Instead you just need to transform the value (code in Scala):

```
val df = spark.read.option("ignoreLeadingWhitespace", "true").csv("trouble.csv")
  .withColumn("_c2", regexp_replace($"_c2", """\\/""", "/")
df.show(false)
+---+---+------------------------------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2                           |
+---+---+------------------------------+
|1  |2  |Learn more https://example.com|
+---+---+------------------------------+
```

(note `ignoreLeadingWhitespace=true` that I used to skip spaces following commas)

And reverse on save:

```
df.withColumn("_c2", regexp_replace($"_c2", "/", """\\/"""))
  .write.option("quoteAll", "true").option("escape", "\u0000").csv("trouble2.csv")

$ cat trouble2.csv/*.csv
"1","2","Learn more https:\/\/example.com"
```

(here used `quoteAll=true` to force quoting all fields just as it was in input and `escape=\0` to turn off escaping quotes - without it you get double backslashes, because it tries to escape the escape character)